# jQuery toggle removes input type checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a checkbox. It will update the value of `$('#express')` that is an input text box. The checkbox will be hidden if I use `.toggle` instead of `.click`.

Is the toggle a reason for my checkbox to be removed or invisible?

**HTML**

```
<form id="addupload" method="post" action="order_history/lightbox/mini-upload-form/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div id="upload">
      <div id="drop">
      Drop Here
     <a>Browse</a>
    <input id="uplo" type="file" name="upl"  />
          </div>
     <ul> </ul>
     </div>
  <div id="formcontent">
        <label class="required" for="unitprice" title="Unit price"><input type="text" id="unitprice" name="unitprice" />Unit price</label>
    <label class="required" for="qty" title="How many pcs"><input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" />Quanity</label>
    <label class="required" for="express" title="Express within China"><input type="text" id="express"  name="express" />Express</label>
    <label class="required" for="linkURL" title="Insert a full URL http:\\"><input type="text" id="linkURL" name="linkURL" />Link</label>
        <label  for="yourdesc"   title="Describe your need clearly">Description<textarea id="yourdesc" name="yourdesc"></textarea></label>
            <label for="shunfeng" title="SF is RMB25 for 1kg ">Express ?<input type="checkbox" id="shunfeng" class="shunfeng" name="shunfeng" /></label>
            <label for="formsubmit" class="nocontent" id="uptest"><input  type="button"  id="submitButton" href="#" class="progress-button" onClick="upload()" value="Add to order" /><strong>Note:</strong> Items marked <img src="order_history/images/required.jpg" alt="Required marker" width="20" height="20" /> are required fields</label>
    </div>
 </form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#shunfeng").toggle(
function(){ 
 $('#express').val("25");
 }, function(){
     $('#express').val("0");
     }
 );
```

**CSS**

```
.shunfeng{
width:15px;
height:15px;}
```

Comment: That form of `toggle()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9. Are you using a later release?

Comment: It hide the element from screen and also remove the data from post and get requests.

Comment: at least there is not any id `#express` in your HTML code

Comment: @KingKing is that you down voted the question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `$.toggle(fn, fn);` which you are using was deprecated in *jQuery 1.8* and removed in *jQuery 1.9*

Moreover I think you need `change` event

```
$("#shunfeng").change(function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#express').val("25"); //If checked set value to 25
    } else {
        $('#express').val("0"); //If unchecked set value to 0
    }
});
```

Comment: your script adds the 25 value to #express but on change it won't add 0 I am using jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: yes it is, but its strange that it doesn't work for me, it adds 25 but won't add 0 when unchecked

Comment: @user3150692, Your HTML is good and code works. Are you getting any error. Can you check your browser console? And __How do I know who has downvoted your question__

Comment: closed the browser and opened it again, it is working as I wanted. thanks buddy you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have a DOM element with id express.

It works fine with jQuery 1.8

Here is a working fiddle.

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/nidhinsg/LPNDw/1/)

Else the reason may be because of the Jquery you imported. Is there any console error? It would help..
If its jquery 1.9 try to use change instead of toggle.

```
$("#shunfeng").change(
function(){ console.log("A");
 $('#express').val("25");
 }, function(){
     $('#express').val("0");
     }
 );
```

Comment: it won't set to 0  I am using jquery-1.10.2.js